# Module.exports function returning 'undefined' for variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following js file that has exports:

```
module.exports = {
  setClientAuthToken: function(authToken) {
    setClientAuthToken(authToken);
  },
  getClientAuthToken: function() {
    getClientAuthToken();
  }
};

var clientAuthToken;

function setClientAuthToken(authToken) {
  clientAuthToken = authToken;
}

function getClientAuthToken() {
  console.log('here!!!!!!');
  console.log('auth token' + clientAuthToken);
  if (!clientAuthToken) {
    console.error("Client Auth Token has not been set");
  } else {
    return clientAuthToken;
  }
}
```

Both functions work and are called successfully, but the `clientAuthToken` variable returned from the `getClientAuthToken` is 'undefined'.

When I log the auth token in the function itself, I can see that it has been set correctly. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to `export` the variable in `module.exports` too?

Comment: `getClientAuthToken: function() {
    getClientAuthToken();
  }` does not have a return. you could write `getClientAuthToken: getClientAuthToken` instead as the additional function is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the clientAuthToken variable returned from the getClientAuthToken
>   is 'undefined'.

Because you are not returning anything.

Add `return` to the function `getClientAuthToken`:

```
module.exports = {
  setClientAuthToken: function(authToken) {
    setClientAuthToken(authToken);
  },
  getClientAuthToken: function() {
    return getClientAuthToken(); // <-- return
  }
};
```

Comment: We have all been there :) Happy to help